# Exiting the stream NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, worker-thread

Only 'text' is output to the console, but 'text2' and 'text3' are not output, because exit from the stream is faster. This is the most simplified code of the real project structure. I can't figure out why this is happening and what to do about it.

This is the stream handler:

```
async function func1() {
  await console.log('text2')
}

async function func() {
  await console.log('text')
  await func1();
  await console.log('text3')
}

async function handler() {
  await func()
  await process.exit(123)
}

handler();
```

The only thing I can add is that the code above is contained in a handler.js file and is run like this:

```
const {Worker} = require('worker_threads')

const myWorker = new Worker('./handler.js')

myWorker.on('exit', (data) => {
  console.log('Worker exit: ' + data)
})
```

И вывод следующий:
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cwfJ.png)

Comment: nothing you have here is asynchronous. So awaiting does nothing. Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem as this code [behaves as expected](https://jsfiddle.net/k34vbcLt/) with all three log statements printed to the console

Comment: Your code from the link works correctly because it is not running on a thread worker_threads

Comment: like i said, you need to update your question with a reproducible example as there is not enough information to debug your problem. please see the link i posted above

Comment: I posted a sufficient example that shows the essence of the problem. Run this code on a stream and you will see that it only outputs 'text'

Comment: is there a reason you are calling `process.exit`? the worker will exit on its own here and behave properly.

Comment: This code doesn't make sense, but in my original code it's the only way to stop the thread when the condition is right.

Comment: I have offered up my two cents, might not be what you are looking for but this ended up being an interesting question and i thought id add what i found after an hour of research. I also upvoted as i think what youre really asking is more clear now (how to properly exit a worker thread)

Answer (score 2):

Despite the lack of a true, reproducible example, for your use case; this question is interesting and the answer wasn't obvious to find. I am not as read up on the `worker_threads` API as id like to be but ill offer my two cents.

After doing some research/testing (and not really having much to go on in terms of your specific use case), i believe it is because you are calling `process.exit` inside the worker thread. Since worker threads add their console statements to the main threads call stack, it takes some time before they all run. Calling `process.exit` here must be removing any remaining operations from that worker on the main threads call stack before they have a chance to run.

When you remove `process.exit`, all log statements run and the worker exits naturally.

If you need to close the worker thread at a particular point in time (which is what i think the real question here is), you might be better off sending a message back to the main thread using the [`parentPort.postMessage()`](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#workerpostmessagevalue-transferlist) method and then having the main thread terminate the worker:

```
// worker.js
const {parentPort} = require('worker_threads');
async function func1() {
  await console.log('text2')
}

async function func() {
  await console.log('text')
  await func1();
  await console.log('text3')
}

async function handler() {
  await func()
  parentPort.postMessage({kill: true});
}

handler();
```

Then listen for that [message event](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#event-message_1) and [terminate](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#workerterminate) the worker from the main thread:

```
// index.js
const {Worker} = require('worker_threads')

const myWorker = new Worker('./handler.js')

myWorker.on('exit', (data) => {
  console.log('Worker exit: ' + data)
})

myWorker.on('message', async msg => {
  if (msg.kill) {
     console.log('killing worker with code');
     await myWorker.terminate();
  }
})
```

There are some gatchas here as the `terminate` method terminates the thread "as soon as possible" and you are relying on events and will need to prevent the worker from continuing on while the main thread executes the terminate method. However, without more information i cant be of much help. From our comments it might also be worth looking into [child processes](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) for this. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for this option, looks cool. I will definitely try it